# Unable To Run Nightrain On Ubuntu 64bit 14.04LTS Please Help

Tags: 14.04, python

```
$ ./nightrain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/naetech/Applications/Repositories/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "/home/naetech/Sites/nightrain/build/nightrain/out00-PYZ.pyz/Classes.GUI", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/naetech/Applications/Repositories/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "/home/naetech/Sites/nightrain/build/nightrain/out00-PYZ.pyz/wx.html2", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/naetech/Applications/Repositories/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 414, in load_module
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'd start by `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`

Answer (score 1):

The library `libGL.so.1` is part of the packages below, listed by the command `apt-file search --regex libGL\.so\.1$ | awk -F: '{print $1}'`.

```
fglrx
fglrx-updates
libgl1-mesa-glx
nvidia-304
nvidia-304-updates
nvidia-340
nvidia-340-updates
nvidia-346
nvidia-346-updates
primus-libs
```

Therefore, if you have an AMD GPU:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-updates
```

for an NVidia, better look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)...